# How do I replace this text in VIM?

Tags: vim, grep

```
:%s/oldword/newword/g
```

That's how I usually do it. Now, I want to replace `abc.com` with `<%= domain %>`.  How can I do that? (The symbols don't work when you type them in vim command line)

```
:%s/abc.com/<%= domain %>/g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the '.' and '%' characters. Like this `:%s/abc\.com/<\%= domain \%>/g`

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape `.` (so that it does not match any character) and `%`. Try this:

```
:%s/abc\.com/<\%= domain \%>/g
```